# flutter setup on android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout

I'm facing problem in flutter setup on android studio. how to resolve this problem ?
anyone have faced this problem plz help me out.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1581)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1476)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1483)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1288)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1251)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:732)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:849)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Insta`enter code here`ll.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: did you try out to delete cache files of android studio like in `.gradle` folder  ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your 'JAVA_HOME' path variable is set and you have installed Java correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this kind of issue. All I did was delete the .gradle folder from C:\Users<youraccount> . Try rerunning after deleting that and it will build it again.

After that maybe you will face issues in your app/gradle file in android folder in the project. If you open that, there may be errors of `GradleException` which you have to replace with `FilenotFoundException`

Also, do run `flutter doctor` to know about any issues present in your setup.

Please do let me know if it works for you.